# enumerate: custom list alignment

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[1)]
        \item aaa 
        \item bbb
        \item [2\textit{bis})] ccc
        \item ddd
        \item eee
        \item fff
        \item [5\textit{bis})] ggg
        \item [5\textit{ter})] hhh
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

How can I align 2bis, 5bis, and 5ter items with the other numbers?

Comment: By "align", do you mean "left-align"? (Right now the numerals are right-aligned.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far your items' labels are right aligned, Do you like to have left aligned? With use of the `enumitem` package you can simple left align items' labels with option `align=left`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*, label=\arabic*), widest=7bis), align=left]
        \item aaa
        \item bbb
        \item [2\textit{bis})] ccc
        \item ddd
        \item eee
        \item fff
        \item [5\textit{bis})] ggg
        \item [5\textit{ter})] hhh
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you drop `widest=...` from `enumerate` options, than you will get:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the last one is what I wanted. I have also added the option labelindent=(length) to have the full list of items not aligned with relation to the text above and below.